# AngularJS dynamically get and object

Tags: angularjs

I have this in one of my controllers (notice the id):

```
Post.get
        id: "2"

        # Success
      , (response) ->
        $scope.post = response

        # Error
      , (response) ->
```

But what I'd like to do is some how dynamically get a specific post i.e. `{{getPost("2")}}`

Sorry if what I'm asking is pretty obvious but I'm a beginner and have been stuck on this for hours. Could someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better practice to separate server request into factory, for example lets call your factory jonFactory and your App jonApp so now we have services.js file that includes all our factories/services.

```
angular.module('jonApp',[]).
    factory('jonFactory', function($http) {
        function.getPost = function(id) {
            var url = "your url for post";
            var args = { 'id': id };
            $http.post(url, args)
                .success(function(data){
                    return data;
                });
        }
    });
```

### Hope I understood your right

Your Ctrl should use your factory, so you have to include it through:

```
angular.module('jonApp.controllers', []).
    controller('JonController', function($scope, jonFactory) {
        $scope.getPostById = function(id) {
            return jonFactory.getPost(id);
        }
});
```

and in the view just display the function result:

```
 <div>{{getPostById(2)}}</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I've should've explained my question in a clearer way.. Please see my edit

Comment: @Jon so the problem is to write proper ctrl that will represent the data in the view?

Comment: I edited in what I have so far in my controller.  Each `Blog` has many `Posts`

Comment: Sorry m8, I'm not sure if I understood your problem.
You trying to fetch data dynamically? 
You do want to provide id?

Comment: Thanks, this was similar to what I tried before but now it's causing my app to freeze but I guess that's a different question.

Comment: mb there is problem that caused by async. so just put make outside var like $scope.displayPost, put the returned data into it and do $scope.$apply()/$scope.$digest() after you intit.

Comment: you can also solve it by using $q, please contact me if you want me to explain, or goolge